# Djangosum two fields from different tables

Tags: django

I use the code below to sum fields in different tables. However, when there's no record that matches table1_id in table2, django returns None

```
Table 1
id    val
1     2
2     3

Table 2
id    val    table1_id
1     5      1
```

The query below would return:

```
7
None
```

How would I return:

```
7
3
```

Django query:

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(
    some_filters
).annotate(
    var=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('val') + F('table2__val'), output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `Coalesce` from `django.db.models.functions` solved my issue

```
SomeModel.objects.filter(
    some_filters
).annotate(
    var=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('val') + Coalesce(F('table2__val'), 0), output_field=FloatField()
    )
)
```